# Could not create a material card element inside material tab in angular 5 material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like to create a card inside a material tab. I am using following code:

```html
<div fxLayout>
  <span fxFlex></span>
  <div fxFill fxFlex id="user-home-container">
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="Newest">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <app-aurora-questions-list></app-aurora-questions-list>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Most votes">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <app-aurora-questions-list></app-aurora-questions-list>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Unanswered">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <app-aurora-questions-list></app-aurora-questions-list>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Intresting">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <app-aurora-questions-list></app-aurora-questions-list>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
    <button mat-fab color="primary" id="ask-question">+</button>
  </div>
  <span fxFlex></span>
</div>
```

The card is not displayed in the tab. The css is defined as follows:

```css
#user-home-container {
  margin-top: 15px;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.tab-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#ask-question {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

What am i doing incorrectly? I am using Angular with Angular Material and Angular Flex Layout.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in [this StackBlitz](https://angular-material2-issue-oezi4y.stackblitz.io) example. Note: I did change your css ```.tab-content``` class to ```margin: 20px``` to make it more card-like. Are you getting an error of some kind?

Comment: Can you add your app's module?

Comment: Updated the complete code that I am using

Comment: Stackblitz? It could be something wrong with your imports or maybe a CSS issue..

Comment: I most probably suspect that its a css issue. The components are too nested and therefore posting all that code would not be possible. I think I should do some digging.